# ¿Como abrir la ventana de variables en NetBeans para depurar?

Tags: netbeans, variables, depuración

Quise depurar un programa pero al presionar Step into (F7) no abrió la sección para observar el valor que adquieren las variables llamada "Variables"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces alguien sabe como abrir esta ventana?

Comment: Hola jose manuel quiñones garibay, si vas a la pestaña ***Window***, surfeas hasta ***Debugging***, el primer indice de la lista te abre la ventana variables (si está activo el debug, sino queda preparada para abrirse).

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! ¡Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Un placer maestro!!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estés debugueando el proyecto, vas a `Window -> Debugger -> Variables`

Comment: Con un comentario bastaba.

Comment: @CandidMoe de hecho no, a muchos nos paso que cerramos por equivocación la ventana mientras estábamos depurando yo le doy su +1